# i have preorder and in-order of a tree. how to generate array representation of this

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

consider the below binary search tree

```
     a
    /  \
   b    c
  /      \
 d        e
```

the pre-order is `a b d c e`
in-order is `d b a c e`
and array representation is `a b c d \0 \0 e`

now the question is

root of a tree is given and I can generate preorder and inorder from that root using the below code

```
void preorder(struct node *root){
    if(root==NULL){
        return;
    }

    printf("%d\n",root->data);
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);

}

void inorder(struct node *root){
    if(root==NULL){
        return;
    }

    
    inorder(root->left);
    printf("%d\n",root->data);
    inorder(root->right);

}
```

now I can store this preorder and inorder in an array. and from these two arrays.. I want array representation of the BST

Comment: That's a reasonable thing to want. Let us know when you have a specific question about it? (We're not here to write your code for you.)

Comment: I was taught, in my Data Structures course, that *preorder*, *inorder* and *post order* were different ways of traversing the same tree.  You may want to consider how you traverse your tree, rather than creating new ones.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i dont want any traversal. i wanna generate array representation of tree from linkedlist representation of tree

Comment: I recommend using a loop to traverse the tree rather than recursion.  Recursion will add to the limited stack space.

Comment: thank you @ThomasMatthews. i will use iteration instead of recursion

Comment: Are you sure the array shall contain `\0`. I would expect `a b c d e`

Comment: @4386427 https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/binary-trees-in-c-array-representation-and-travers/

Comment: You have a binary tree, but you don't have a search tree.  That makes your question confusing, because this kind of array representation is not used for binary search trees.  It's usually used for heaps.  Also, sometimes you say you want to make it from the preorder and inorder arrays, and other times you say you want to make it from the linked tree.

Comment: @MattTimmermans this question was answered by 4386427 (thank you :)).  and in fact, tree can be represented in an array but contains white spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array index can be calculated like:

```
Root->arrayIndex = 0

LeftChild->arrayIndex = 2 * parentNode->arrayIndex + 1
RightChild->arrayIndex = 2 * parentNode->arrayIndex + 2
```

To make it easy, let's assume you already know the resulting array size (if not, it's easy to calculate).

```
char array[ARRAY_SIZE];
memset(array, '\0', ARRAY_SIZE);  // Fill the whole array with \0
```

Now you want to overwrite some of the array elements with values from the tree. It can be done with something like:

```
void fill_array(struct node *root, char* array, int index){
    if(root==NULL){
        return;
    }

    array[index] = root->data;
    fill_array(root->left, array, 2*index + 1);
    fill_array(root->right, array, 2*index + 2);
}
```

and call it like:

```
struct node *root = ROOT_OFTHE_TREE;

char array[ARRAY_SIZE];
memset(array, '\0', ARRAY_SIZE);  // Fill the whole array with \0

fill_array(root, array, 0);

// Add code to print the array
```